# Verifying an uploaded File's content type using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, file

How can I verify a files content type without using the files extension or mime type using ASP.Net.

I don't want to use the mime type because it appears to be determined by the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FindMimeFromData() function in UrlMon.dll (using pinvoke).

See [this page for an example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/urlmon.FindMimeFromData) and this [MSDN page for the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107.aspx) of the function.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on file type. For many file types, you can examine the header of the file, which is generally prior to the first 0 char in the file. I used to have some code that examined picture types, so I might be able to find it somewhere.

But, there are file types that will not have this form of header, like XML (yeah, this is a cheap example, but it was easy for me to think of ;->). I believe all graphics types will have the header, as will other binary file types.

As Andrew has mentioned, the header is not 100%. But, it is unlikely it will be a hack attack if the file is "malformed". It is more likely a corrupt upload or upload of a corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to verify a file is of the given extension type.

You could create a white-list of formats (png, jpg, zip etc) and examine the file header to determine whether it conforms to the expected format.

Even that is not fool-proof though since the file content itself may be malformed in a way that would only become apparent when an attempt to load it is made.